# disabling TCP stack in kernel and creating Userspace TCP stack -- call it a server for something -- what may be the challenges

Tags: c

if I malfunctioned my computer TCP stack in kernel just commenting out single important line of code or compiling with excluding TCP stack and install. Then What are the steps in I need to take in coding. Do I need to Implement Ethernet (if creates layer 2 Socket in my stack implementation) then do I need to implement `IP` because that comes with if I am using layer 2 socket then implement TCP (this is what final code will be)

If that's so

Then what are the supported protocols I need to implement to cover ethernet layer, Ip layer and (TCP layer -- that I can know I may have used it in code)

Can anyone please tell the machining protocols with each layer
`whats before?-->ethernet --> ip -- tcp --> http` <--protocol names please that may be needed

the whole thing is just for as a research thing or learning for my self or just may be programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you want to be able to do something like request `https://example.com` from a web server.

For this the following procotols are diretly necessary:

- HTTPS (i.e. HTTP and TLS), but that's usually already implemented in user space, no change here
- DNS to resolve `example.com` to an IP address. Usually implemented in user space as well, based on UDP
- UDP to run DNS on top of. Usually implemented in the kernel on top of IP.
- TCP to run HTTPS on top of. Usually implemented in the kernel on top of IP.
- IP to run both TCP and UDP on top of. Usually implemented in the kernel on top of Ethernet.
- Ethernet to send/receive IP packages. Usually implemented in the kernel, with the help of hardware-specific NIC drivers.

But even if you had implemented those, you wouldn't be done. For example, you wouldn't know what your local IP address is.

To do this, you'd implement DHCP. You could get away without implementing this, if you just configured your IP address to a fixed value (as long as it's within the allowed range of your network and doesn't conflict with other devices, this is not a problem).

But when you try to send your first IP packet to the DNS server, you'd realize that you don't know what Ethernet address you should send that to. So you'd need to implement ARP as well. Again, you *could* theoretically have a static routing table and "fake" the ARP responses by your router this way, but this could be way trickier than just hard-coding the IP adress.

I may have missed some protocol (and I'm sure comments will pop up, if I did), but that should be roughly everything that you'd need to get going.

Comment: Is this ever tried so there may be code for it somewhere may be that also include info?

Comment: Do I need to publish my ip matching domain in my program so on the internet any one can send request using domain. Can u talk about this little bit this dns thing?

Comment: `you wouldn't know what your local IP address is`...`To do this, you'd implement DHCP. You could get away without implementing this, if you just configured your IP address to a fixed value (as long as it's within the allowed range of your network and doesn't conflict with other devices, this is not a problem).` If I do not know the local ip address then can I suppose any valid ip which my router is allows or my ISP allows or valid city wide ip range allows, can u clarify on this?

Comment: and once I finally decide the ip address  if its valid then do I need to `broadcast` it like to other computers connected to my router or ISP or something?

Comment: @user786: You might want to look at [lwIP](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/), which is a small implementation of a TCP/IP stack.

Comment: There's usually nothing like a "city wide" IP address. An IP is either public (i.e. routable on the public internet) or private (i.e. only meaningful within some private network). That private network could be either your local network (i.e. everything behind your router) or something as "large" as whatever unit of management your ISP has set up. You don't need to "broadcast" your IP. Long-range routing has to be done "outside" of your system (i.e. it's not the responsibility of a single TCP/IP stack) and short-range (i.e. within the local network) is handled by ARP and RARP.

Comment: @Hasturkun is this the code of your link how to compile it any doc?https://github.com/ARMmbed/lwip where is main(...)?

Comment: is it linux based lwip?

Comment: @user786: it's a IP stack implementation. It's not a program that you're supposed to launch. It's code that you're supposed to *use in some other program* it has no singular `main` method ... sorry, but you'll have to learn to do a bit more in-depth reading and research. You can't just post every single thing that comes to your mind here and expect ready-made answers. You've set out on a tricky road by trying to do this, even with read-made code. Prepare for some experiments and failures.

Comment: I am really not interested in implementing anything see my other  recent questions which I am focusing on. This question is just to be able to answer simple questions I am asked